# Galleria Deletion Icon

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, galleria

I've been working with the Galleria package to create a image gallery. I'm now wanting to add a deletion tool so that a user can delete any image they so desire.

Using [this](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/photo-manager.html) demo as a baseline, I've taken the elements of code which I need and tried to incorporate it into my gallery page [here](http://www.mapmyfinds.co.uk/development/testgallery.php). The problem is, is that I cannot get the 'bin' icon to appear at the bottom of each image, and hence I'm unable to see whether the function which makes the image disappear from screen actually works. I don't need the code that deletes the image from the server. I'll be dealing with that later on.

I'm really quite new to Javacript and jQuery, so please feel free to speak down to me. But I've been working on this for weeks now and I just can't find a solution.

I just wondered whether someone could perhaps look at this and let me know where I'm going wrong.

Many thanks and regards

Comment: your page url goes nowhere like a demo page...

Comment: Hi @balexandre, I'm sorry I'm not sure what you mean. If you look at the URL, it's a demo on the jQuery website. Kind regards

Comment: "into my gallery page here" <-- here goes nowhere

Comment: @balexandre, my sincere apologies and many thanks for highlighting this. I have now added the gallery. Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding this style to your CSS rule:

```
.btn-delete {
    width: 14px; height: 14px;
    margin: 38px 0 0 66px;
    position: absolute;
}
.icon-remove { background-position: -312px 0; }
.icon-white { background-image: url('http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/img/glyphicons-halflings-white.png'); }
```

and in your jQuery:

```
$(".galleria-image").append(
     "<span class='btn-delete icon-remove icon-white'></span>");

$(".btn-delete").live("click", function() {
    var img = $(this).closest(".galleria-image").find("img");

    alert('Deleting image... ' + $(img).attr("src"));
    return false;
});
```

this will do something like:

[image]

Now, you can simply send an ajax request using `$.get()` for example, passing the ID/SRC of the image that the user wanted to delete and refresh your code/remove all images that belong to that selected one.

Comment: Hi @balexandre, many thanks for this. If at all possible I'd like to use the icon and functionality from the demo. Could you tell me please is this possible? Kind regards

Comment: the icon, just change it to whatever you want, it's in he CSS. regarding the "functionality from the demo", I don't follow...

Comment: Hi, my apologies for not making this clear. I've put together a really quick script here: http://www.mapmyfinds.co.uk/development/delete.php to show how I would like each image to look and act upon the delete icon being selected. Please forgive me for asking, I'm really very new to jQuery, but could you also please confirm whether both elements of code go into my gallery script or the main files i.e. `galleria-1.2.7.min.js` and `galleria.twelve.css`. Kind regards

Comment: Hi @balexandre, this is absolutely fantastic. It's just what I was after, thank you so very much. I do just have a very simple question thugh. Could you possibly tell me please how I woud increase the border at the bottom of the image and move the 'bin' image a little further down from the image. I didn't want to mess the file up, without knowing what I was changing. Kind regards

Comment: just play around with the `padding` and `margin`.

Comment: That's great. Now onto the hard bit of deleting the actual record? Once again many thanks for all your time, trouble and help, it is greatly appreciated. Kind regards

Comment: you need to do something for your self ... this is not a homework forum. I gave you a good start, continue to learn and if you came up with more questions, ask them here showing what did you already tried. There are plenty of Video Tutorials on jQuery, you should look upon them as well... don't expect us to do all the hard work.

Comment: Hi @balexandre, I'm afraid you've misunderstood. I wasn't asking for anymore help. I was just trying to be friendly, that's all. kind regards